# Can I use Yandex Maps in a Nokiax app?

Tags: nokiax, yandex-maps

I need to use Yandex Maps in an app instead of Here Maps. Could this be possible? Any hints or tricks to help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the rules of using APIs is very simple. If the API is not requiring any parts that are not available in the platform, then it works.

Thus if the API is using parts that are supported in AOSP 4.1.2 API level 16, and using any Google services, then it is likely to work just fine.

And you can always check the compatibility with free online tools very easily. First go to [Online Analyser](http://developer.nokia.com/nokia-x/analyse/) drag and drop the APK there, and let the tool check the compatibility issues.

Then you can also use a real device for testing, just visit [Remote Device Access](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/remote-device-access), and reserve a device for testing your app.

Both steps should onlky take you couple of minutes to complete.

For Yandex maps, you would need to visit their developer site to see how the maps API can be used, and what restrictions they would pose on utilizing the API.